# Create a pivot with joins in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I'm using Psql and need to get values from a table called `activities` via creating a pivot.

At the moment I have a query like this, which produces a table with columns `first_name|email|signup_hash`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(profile.first_name, signup_hash.first_name) AS first_name,
       users.email,
       signup_hash.hash_id,

FROM signup_hash
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = signup_hash.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN profiles ON profiles.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.hash_id = signup_hash.hash_id
WHERE memberships.member_id =?
```

The `activities` table has fields as such: `user_id|activity_name|date_completed|date_created`

Every user has activities with an `activity_name` of "first_login" and "profile_complete" (e.g. activity.name="first_login" and activity.name="profile_complete).

How would I go about joining the activities table so that the final query produces a table with columns: `first_name|email|first_login|profile_complete|signup_hash`?

**Edit**
1)There are not multiple rows of activity_name of "first_login" and "profile_complete" for a particular user
2)what values should the columns first_login & profile_complete contain in the final result? It should display date_completed if the value exists or "N/A" otherwise

Comment: Are there multiple rows  of `activity_name` of "first_login" and "profile_complete"  for a particular user? in `activities` table .   what values should the columns `first_login` & `profile_complete` contain in  your final result .

Comment: 1)There are not multiple rows of activity_name of "first_login" and "profile_complete" for a particular user
2)It should display date_completed if  the value exists or "N/A" otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 more `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s  as follows  and use `CASE` to select the required expression in the result. Note that here i considered `date_completed` to be a `date` column. If it is a character column , then `TO_CHAR` is not required.

```
    SELECT COALESCE(profile.first_name, signup_hash.first_name) AS first_name,
       users.email,
       CASE
           WHEN f_login.user_id IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
           ELSE TO_CHAR(date_completed)
       END first_login,
       CASE
           WHEN p_complete.user_id IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
           ELSE TO_CHAR(date_completed)
       END profile_complete,
       signup_hash.hash_id
FROM signup_hash
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = signup_hash.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN profiles ON profiles.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.hash_id = signup_hash.hash_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id,
          date_completed
   FROM activities
   WHERE activity_name = 'first_login') f_login ON f_login.user_id = signup_hash.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id,
          date_completed
   FROM activities
   WHERE activity_name = 'profile_complete') p_complete ON p_complete.user_id = signup_hash.user_id
WHERE memberships.member_id = ?
```

Comment: wouldn't this create table with 7 columns? `first_name|email|user_id|first_login|user_id|profile_complete|signup_hash`

Comment: No. How do you require it to be?

Comment: ok, I see I the 'case'. This should work. The only thing is that user_id will never be blank, so I think it should be: `WHEN f_login.date_completed IS NULL THEN 'N/A' `

Comment: So . You need both conditions checked separately or together?